# Is it okay to say arrange you a visit?

Tags: phrase-choice, synonyms

Is it okay to invite someone by saying
arrange you a visit, or there is a better way??

Comment: Would you please give us more context? How do you think the phrase should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not okay.
It is simply wrong.

You can't insert a person/pronoun between the verb **arrange** and the object (a visit).

You can arrange a visit for someone or on their behalf. Or you can make arrangements for a visit for them.

There are many verbs that allow the construction you suggest.

You can say: **Please give someone the book** when you mean **please give the book to someone**. Or you can **sing them a song** and so on.

But this construction doesn't work with arrange as the verb generally means either to tidy (the room) or fashion (the flowers) or to make the necessary preparations for something.

An exception might be a phrase such as **arrange them in twos/threes** meaning in groups or two or three etc.

Someone might also say **please arrange him a little (better)**, meaning "arrange his clothing" or "tidy him up", but this would be most unusual.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more natural to say "I will arrange a visit for you".

Comment: Or "Let's arrange a date for you to visit."